# iOS Safari memory issue - crashing on web page load

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Web page is crashing iOS Safari on iPad and iPhone, but no other devices or browsers.

http://www.ultranocturne.com/portraits

It's an isotope portfolio gallery that nobody else seems to have reported an answer that fixes this issue.

I've debugged and removed all CSS warnings to tackle the potential webkit transition incompatibilities, even replaced using a CSS file with ALL webkit lines completely removed.

> **Simulator Debug**
>
> On xcode / safari developer - the page doesn't crash or throw out any warnings

-

> **Device Debug**
>
> Safari developer window closes when the page crashes.
>
> Xcode device console throws this out on crash:

```
Sep 11 20:17:26 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[232] Builtin profile: MobileSafari (sandbox)
Sep 11 20:17:26 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[233] Builtin profile: webbookmarksd (sandbox)
Sep 11 20:17:27 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone webbookmarksd[233] <Notice>: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_MEMORYSTATUS] add: "Operation not permitted" - 0x1
Sep 11 20:17:29 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[234] Builtin profile: syncdefaultsd (sandbox)
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpcd.F5010000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000[221]) <Notice>: (com.apple.xpcd.F5010000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[217]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.timed[217]) <Notice>: (com.apple.timed) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[214]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[214]) <Notice>: (com.apple.lsd) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[200]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.networkd_privileged[200]) <Notice>: (com.apple.networkd_privileged) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[215]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.mobile.installd[215]) <Notice>: (com.apple.mobile.installd) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd[233]) <Notice>: (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd) Idle-exit job was jettisoned. Will bypass throttle interval for next on-demand launch.
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd[233]) <Notice>: (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:47 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Sep 11 20:17:48 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Sep 11 20:17:49 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone MobileSafari[232] <Warning>: Received memory warning.
Sep 11 20:17:51 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone ReportCrash[236] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary
Sep 11 20:17:51 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone ReportCrash[236] <Notice>: Not saving suspended-only Jetsam log because already dumped today.
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.MobileSMS[0x57fa][222]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.MobileSMS[0x57fa]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x37e][201]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x37e]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.tccd[203]) <Notice>: (com.apple.tccd) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x1bd3][202]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x1bd3]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.MobileSMS[0x57fa]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone UserEventAgent[13] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilephone[0x37e]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:54 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilemail[0x1bd3]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:55 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x2403][232]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x2403]) Exited: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:55 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.apple.mobilesafari[0x2403]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
Sep 11 20:17:55 Louis-Lawrences-iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[239] Builtin profile: MobileMail (sandbox)
```

This is everything from page load to crash.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. Tried linting and validating and reducing all requests to a mere 46KB --- can't figure out what's going on. I hope somebody provides an answer.